# sort and merge intervals c#

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a list of segment intervals in 2D space. My Segment class is defined like this:

```
class Segment
{
    public int startPoint { get; set; }
    public int endPoint { get; set; }
    public int commonPoint { get; set; }
}
```

every segment has a start point and an endpoint and common point so I know which segments are collinear. In my main program I read some lines entered by user in this format: {startpoint.X, startPoint.Y, endPoint.X, endPoint.Y}
so the user enters data like this:

```
4 //this is the number of lines  
0 1 2 1  
1 4 1 2  
0 3 2 3  
2 1 6 1
```

here's the code that reads data:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int n = 0; //number of input segments
    n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    string[] values; //hold input segments' startpoints and endpoints
    int x1, y1, x2, y2;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        values = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        x1 = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]); y1 = Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);
        x2 = Convert.ToInt32(values[2]); y2 = Convert.ToInt32(values[3]);

        if (x1 == x2) //this is a vertical line
        {
            if(y1 > y2) //storing the segment intervals form left to right
                verticalSegments.Add(new Segment { startPoint = y2, endPoint = y1, commonPoint = x1 });
            else
                verticalSegments.Add(new Segment { startPoint = y1, endPoint = y2, commonPoint = x1 });
        }
        else // this is a horizontal line
        {
            if (x1 > x2) //storing the segment intervals form left to right
                horizontalSegments.Add(new Segment { startPoint = x2, endPoint = x1, commonPoint = y1 });
            else
                horizontalSegments.Add(new Segment { startPoint = x1, endPoint = x2, commonPoint = y1 });
        }
    }
```

Now I want to call the sort() method on either vertical or horizontal segements to sort the segments in the list by startingPoints (preferably ascending).

I tried editing my Segment class like this:

```
class Segment
{
    public int startPoint { get; set; }
    public int endPoint { get; set; }
    public int commonPoint { get; set; }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        Segment objAsSegment = obj as Segment;
        if (objAsSegment == null) return false;
        else return Equals(objAsSegment);
    }
    public int sortByStartingPointAscending(int startPoint1, int startPoint2)
    {
        return startPoint1.CompareTo(startPoint2);
    }
    public int CompareTo(Segment compareSegment)
    {
        if (compareSegment == null) return 1;
        else
            return this.startPoint.CompareTo(compareSegment.startPoint);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return startPoint;
    }
    public bool Equals(Segment other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;
        return (this.startPoint.Equals(other.startPoint));
    }
}
```

and I called `horizontalSegments.Sort();` in my main method. But I get an error:

`InvalidOperationException was unhandled` at the calling `sort()` line!

Comment: I don't see any question...

Comment: edited :D forgot to ask :D

Comment: `How do I do this?` is  not a question. It is an implicit request of "do it for me". Explain your code, what you have tried for it and what did go wrong...

Comment: what do I do then? I don't know how to do it? How should I edit my question?

Comment: @Eser Ok I edited again

Comment: And I upvoted it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and implement a method which does the required comparisons on two `Segment` objects, and pass it into the `Sort` method of the list..

The signature of the comparison method needs to be as follows (they can be static):

```
public static int CompareSegmentHorizontal(Segment x, Segment y) {
// your code here; return 0 if equal, -1 when x is less than y, and 1 if x is greater then y
}
```

And use it like this:

```
horizontalSegments.Sort(CompareSegmentHorizontal);
```

Minor note: Unlike Java, it's common in C# to write method and property names in PascalCase notation.

Comment: and How do I pass this to the sort method?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `horizontalSegments` is `List<Segment>`, [`List<T>.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx) method requires that T implements `IComparable<T>` interface and you forgot to add it to the declaration of your `Segment` class. It's the reason of InvalidOperationException. `Segment` class already has `CompareTo` method which `IComarable<T>` interface requires. So just add it.

```
class Segment : IComparable<Segment>
```